# Can I see line numbers in the VS2010 editor?

Tags: visual-studio

I spent time searching how to do this but came up with nothing. Is there a simple way I can make the editor show line numbers?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Tools, Options, Text Editor, All Languages, Show Line Numbers

You can also show them only for a specific language.

Comment: You might need to check "Show all settings"

Comment: Thanks. That makes my life a lot easier now :-)

Comment: For someone who uses Visual Studio 2010 express: Tools, Options, General, Line numbers.

Answer (score 3):

In the Tools menu, select Options.  Under Text Editor, All Languages, General, you'll find "Display line numbers".

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165340.aspx

On the menu bar, choose Tools, Options.

In the categories list on the left side of the Options window, expand the Text Editor node.

Expand the All Languages subfolder, and then choose General to set this option globally.